# Mongoose and MongoError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting an odd error. I'm guessing it is because I'm not handling the error correctly to get more information. Here is the error I am getting. I have searched on here without success in finding something similar. The docs are just confusing me.

```
{"name":"MongoError","level":"error","service":"user-service"}
```

Here is my connection script:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      logger   = require('./logging');

async function connect(){

  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fdData")
    .catch(error => {
      logger.error(error);
  });
}

async function disconnect(){
    await mongoose.disconnect()
    logger.info('DB disconnected');
}

module.exports= {connect, disconnect}
}

module.exports= {connect, disconnect}
```

And here is where I am calling it. (This is just a small snippet of the script).

UPDATED 1/20/20 @ 1024am PST.

- (Removed db.connect() and db.disconnect from weather.js. db.connect
  happens on app.js. weather.js checks mongoose ready state and reports
  a state of 1 (connected).
- Added mongoose Op result to logger so now we see the result of the
  attempted mongoose op in the console.

```
//schema setup

const weatherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        condition: String,
        temp: Number,
        windDir: String,
        windSpd: Number,
        windGust: Number,
        windChill: String,
        humidity: Number,
        icon: String,
        tempIcon: String,
        date: String,
        updated: String,
    });

const weatherWarningSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        warning: String,
        warningStart: String,
        warningExpire: String,
        warningBody: String,
        id: String,
        date: String,
    });

const Weather = mongoose.model("weather", weatherSchema);
const Warning = mongoose.model("warning", weatherWarningSchema);

currentWeather=[];

async function saveWeather(update){

/////////commented Out for troubleshooting//////////
    // await db.connect() 
    //     .then(error=>{logger.error(error)
/////////end comments/////////////
            Weather.findOneAndUpdate({date: update.date}, 
                {   date:update.date, 
                    condition:update.condition,
                    temp:update.temp, 
                    windChill:update.windChill, 
                    windDir:update.windDir, 
                    windSpd:update.windSpd, 
                    windGust:update.windGust, 
                    humidity:update.humidity, 
                    icon:update.icon, 
                    tempIcon:update.tempIcon, 
                    updated:update.updated}, 
                {upsert:true,
                new: true,}, 
                function(error, result){
                    if (error){
                        logger.error(error);
                    } else{
                        console.log(result);
                        logger.info('Weather Saved to DB '+moment().utcOffset(-8).format('HH:mm'))
                    }
                })
                console.log('Mongoose Ready State: '+mongoose.connection.readyState)
///////commented out for troubleshooting////////
        // }).then((res, error)=>{
        //     if(error){
        //         logger.error(error)
        //     }
            // db.disconnect();
        // })
/////////end comments/////////

}
```

This is the complete initial output in console:

> Getting Burn Data...
>
> Updating Weather Data...
>
> (node:3890) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
>
> (node:3890) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>
> {"message":"Dashboard Server is running on 3000","level":"info","service":"user-service"}
>
> {"message":"Crewsense token is current","level":"info","service":"user-service"}
>
> {"message":"A911 Token is Current","level":"info","service":"user-service"}
>
> Mongoose Ready State: 1
>
> {
>     _id: 5e25ef3d8c936f22f7722326,
>     date: '2020-01-20',
>     __v: 0,
>     condition: 'Sunny',
>     humidity: 96,
>     icon: 'sunny.png',
>     temp: 34,
>     tempIcon: 'https://cdn.aerisapi.com/wxicons/v2/cold.png',
>     updated: '01/20/20 10:19',
>     windChill: '34',
>     windDir: 'N',
>     windGust: 0,
>     windSpd: 0
>   }
>
> {"message":"Weather Saved to DB 10:19","level":"info","service":"user-service"}
>
> Saving Burn Data...
>
> Burn Data Saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!!!

Mongoose and MongoDB were operating correctly. The issue was in the assignment of the `currentWeather` array. I was pushing the new data onto the array instead of replacing it. So my script was continuously placing `currentWeather[0]` into my DB which is why it would work once and not again.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you `db disconnected`, whats happening is that you're not waiting for the promise returned from the `updateOne` function.

You should add an `await` there to fix this.

```
await db.connect()
    .then(async (error) {
       logger.error(error)
       console.log('Saving Weather... '+mongoose.connection.readyState) //"Saving Weather...1"

       await Weather.updateOne({date: update.date}, 
                   ... )

    }).then((res, error)=>{
       if(error){
          logger.error(error)
       }
       db.disconnect();
   })
```

Comment: Tom I cant place await in front of Weather.updateOne. It tells me it is not an async function.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the .then() with Weather.updateOne() complete before the next .then()?

Comment: No, the promise for it is ignored so the code does not wait for it.

Comment: I updated my code above since I have been trying to figure it out w/o success. I have added additional output to my console and I updated that output as well. The initial running of the code works fine. But when my app calls the function to run again at a timed interval the output is this: (next comment)

Comment: Updating Weather Data...
Mongoose Ready State: 1
{
  _id: 5e25ef3d8c936f22f7722326,
  date: '2020-01-20',
  __v: 0,
  condition: 'Sunny',
  humidity: 96,
  icon: 'sunny.png',
  temp: 34,
  tempIcon: 'https://cdn.aerisapi.com/wxicons/v2/cold.png',
  updated: '01/20/20 10:19',
  windChill: '34',
  windDir: 'N',
  windGust: 0,
  windSpd: 0
}
{"message":"Weather Saved to DB 10:31","level":"info","service":"user-service"}

Comment: As you can see it checks mongoose's ready state and that is good 1(connected). Then gets the data which is correct. but if you see the key 'Updated' says 10:19 when the script was run at 10:31. So Mongoose is still not updating the DB for some reason.

Comment: You sure `updated:update.updated` contains the current date?